# How to disable this toast from appearing when I enter or exit fullscreen: "Press (fn) F to exit full screen"?

Tags: fullscreen

How to disable this toast from appearing when I enter or exit fullscreen: "Press (fn) F to exit full screen"? This toast stays there for quite a few seconds and I don't like that.

I see this issue in chromium browser (edge)

[image]

Comment: Is this one app or all? I've never seen Fn F for fullscreen.

Comment: Second report of the same thing later the same day - seems to be Chrome - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/455311/is-there-a-way-to-disable-reminders-of-how-to-leave-full-screen-mode