# Is there a way to disable reminders of how to leave full screen mode?

Tags: google-chrome, shortcut, fullscreen

At some point when I updated I started getting little toast notices whenever I swapped from a windowed screen to a full-screen screen.

[image: Toast notice that reads "Press (fn) F to exit full screen"]

I use desktop spaces frequently, so I see this dozens of times per day as I'm working... I really just don't need it and I don't remember it doing this in the past. Is there a way to disable it?

I'm running an M1 MBP with Ventura 13.2. Running Chrome 110.

Comment: This is not a Mac alert, probably being caused by your browser

Comment: So... I need to poke around in Chrome?

Comment: "So... I need to poke around in Chrome?"  -- Ideally, don't use it! ;-) There are much better browsers, without the disadvantages.

Comment: @benwiggy I use edge and also facing the issue. it's chromium based

Comment: Seems to have already been an issue [11 years ago](https://superuser.com/questions/398945/disable-the-youve-gone-full-screen-notification-in-chrome), and [more recently](https://www.reddit.com/r/uBlockOrigin/comments/ep6dfw/anyway_to_stop_google_chromes_press_esc_to_exit/). The answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28434311/can-i-disable-the-youve-gone-full-screen-notification-in-chrome-with-chrome-e) consider it to be a usabilty feature for people who accidentally trigger Full Screen mode. And I did some poking, didn't find anything useful in chrome://flags.

Comment: PS: Use https://arc.net/ if you can't ditch Chrome :-)

Comment: Vivaldi is an excellent browser. Firefox is still going strong. I haven't found any compelling deficiencies in Safari, tbh.

Comment: @benwiggy There might be some extensions which only exist in Chrome/Firefox, and/or sites which insist on Chrome.

Comment: Browser-specific sites? I thought we were over that 15 years ago!

Comment: @benwiggy Had some recently which did work but just looked bad in Safari. So it still seems to be an issue sometimes.